# lightning:inputAddress with AddressLookup does not autocomplete all fields for some addresses

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using the lightning:inputAddress standard component. And following the sample from the [online docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputAddress/example) with the *showAddressLookup="true"*. 
I'm seeing that on some addresses the autocomplete does not populate the province field.
Here is a screenshot.
[image]

It works OK on some addresses, but I need it to work the same way every time.